# React JS - TDD - Advice

Tags: reactjs, tdd

I am looking to develop a React JS app, but I would like to go about it from a TDD perspective. I am looking to develop a test suite for this endeavor such that I can run the tests in Chrome, Firefox, Edge, and Safari. Then write DEV code around these tests to make the tests pass.

I have researched Enzyme, and Jest. Both of these frameworks look more like unit test frameworks as opposed to UI functional test framework (something like Webdriver / Selenium). It is more critical for me to verify that the appropriate UI elements appear on the page as expected as opposed to verify that React components are rendered.

Can someone please advice me on what frameworks and packages to use to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

As per my understanding, React Snapshot testing with Jest would be suitable for your purpose. 
You can read more about it here: https://jestjs.io/docs/en/snapshot-testing

If you are more keen on testing the functionality, using Puppeteer would be a good idea.

Comment: Snapshot testing is not the right approach for TDD. https://hackernoon.com/snapshot-testing-react-components-with-jest-744a1e980366. Furthermore, Puppeteer does not support Safari and Firefox as per my research.